# Shell: how to use 2 variables with for condition

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I need to use 2 variables with for condition.
For example,

```
cat days
01072017
02072017
03072017

cat hours
00:00
01:00
02:00
03:00
```

my shell script sample

```
 for i in `cat days` & j in `cat hours`
    do
    cat file | grep $i $j >data-$i-$j
    done
```

I want an output of 3 days * 4hours = 12 files redirected with corresponding data-day-hour

Comment: see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 on reading files in bash... add few lines of `file` to question... you probably want to quote `$i $j` inside double quotes..

Comment: If I'm reading your comment correctly you want nested loops, not a lock-step single loop through both files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a nested for loop

```
   for i in `cat days` 
      do 
        for j in `cat hours`
        do
        cat file | grep  "$i $j"  >data-${i}-${j}
      done
    done
```

Answer (score 3):

The standard solution for such problem is to make two loops:

```
for i in $(<days); do
     for j in $(<hours); do
           grep "$i $j" file > data-"$i-$j"
     done
done
```

Notice that I changed backticks to `$()` for command substitution, eliminated dead cats, and added double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one-liner command to run multiloop , for example you have to restart service on different hosts with different service parameters 
**"i"** is for host id and **"j "** is for service name parameter

```
for i in 1 2 3 4;do  ssh host$i 'for j in A B C D; do sudo systemctl restart service_$j; done'; done
```

**Note:** you must change the **"i"** and **"j"** values to your requirements